# Spaces in Isotope Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

We can't figure our why there are large extra spaces in the Work section layout. Can anyone help?

http://new-had.herrmanneasyeditdemo.com/#work

Comment: Seems that there's a loading delay and the "isotope-item" class doesn't get applied right away. As a result your elements are all `div`s which standard `display:block` positioning that drops all elements down below it.

Comment: Please hit refresh a couple of times on the above link. Can you tell if there is still a loading delay?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the loading issue with your div's showing before your images, you need to load your images using imagesLoaded. This prevents just the div's from showing before isotope is called. Since you are using isotope v1.56, not v2, it is included in that version of isotope. Change your custom.js (at line 107) isotope call to this:

```
var $container = $('#portfolio-container');
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
$container.isotope({
    resizable: false,
    itemSelector : ".item",
    masonry : {
        columnWidth : 1,
        gutterWidth: 1,
    }

});
});
```

To fix your layout issue is more complicated since I'm not sure you can fit all your images in a seamless grid using isotope v1.56 and masonry ( most often you need to rearrange them for sizes to fit without white space). You would need to update to isotope v2 and load the [packery layout option](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metafizzy/isotope-packery/master/packery-mode.pkgd.min.js) after isotope and then set your code up as so, for them to fit together.

```
var $container = $('#portfolio-container');
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
$container.isotope({
layoutMode: 'packery',
itemSelector: '.item'

});
});
```

You will also have to change line 349:

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
    $('#portfolio-container').isotope('layout');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added the js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js script and added the above code to the custom.js file, but I am not seeing any changes. Did I did everything correctly?

Comment: Update. We changed the order of the images and that seemed to removed all the spaces except for one. Is this normally how it works?

Comment: Yes. I am updating my answer with a bit more info about it right now

Comment: I made the updates as you suggested, but it still doesn't seem to be working correctly. Can you hit refresh and see if I made any mistakes or is it simply the script not working correctly?

Comment: All the thumbnails now do not display until I hit the "Industry" link from the menu. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to change line 138 to `$(window).resize(function(){
  $('#portfolio-container').isotope('layout');
 });` and you need to remove all the isotope  Isotope CSS3 transitions near line 1106 in base-skeleton-alia.css. Isotope v2 does not need this css.

Comment: You didn't add the packery layout mode js file. That is the main issue

Comment: The packery layout has been added, but unfortunately I am not seeing any difference. There are still some spaces. Any ideas?

Comment: I see you still have the older isotope CSS active. That may be an issue plus you seem to be adding some CSS3 animations?